# Is data from the server also part of the Model in MVC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is probably a simple question, I am trying to use MVC to build my App.

Is data from the server also part of the "Model", in MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. In most cases you'll have the .xib file as the view, the .m files as the controller(-ish) and the web as the model.

Comment: I am also using Core Data in my App, so I guess they are just both the Model? Thanks :)

Comment: That is correct. Model is the part that represents the (persistent) information in your system.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to state that your only model is you CoreData model. I would create a couple of controllers responsible for filling your CoreData Model:

- ConnectionController: responsible for fetching data from your server.
- ParseController: responsible for parsing the fetched data in a way the app could read it, lets say XML-nodes.
- DataController: responsible for using the XML to fill or update the CoreData model.

This way your real and only model for the app is the CoreData model. Other parts of your system (the proposed controllers) are responsible for maintaining that model.